# Is it possible to rebuild a single tree?

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt

I can only find documentation for `Model.objects.rebuild()` which rebuilds all trees.

What if I wanted to rebuild a single tree? Is that possible?

If it's not possible - does that mean using `move_node` or `insert_node` results in rebuilding for all trees?

Answer (score 0):

Found `partial_rebuild` which does the job: https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mptt.managers.html#mptt.managers.TreeManager.partial_rebuild